# Target each instance of a class on the page for custom background color using CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the same code repeated 3 times on my page, I need to target the ImageSection-hold class and have a different background color for each one.

I am not able to add or remove any classes via HTML or Javascript, this has to be done using CSS.

Attempted:
1.) .ImageSection-hold:nth-of-type(1)
      -This changed all of the backgrounds to the same color
2.) .ImageSection-hold{ background-color: #fff;}
    .ImageSection-hold~.ImageSection-hold{ background-color: #000;}

```
<section class="section ImageSection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ImageSection-hold">
      <div class="ImageSection__desc">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section ImageSection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ImageSection-hold">
      <div class="ImageSection__desc">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section ImageSection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ImageSection-hold">
      <div class="ImageSection__desc">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nth-child` selector. More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```css
.ImageSection:nth-child(1) .ImageSection-hold{
   background-color: red
}
.ImageSection:nth-child(2) .ImageSection-hold{
   background-color: green
}
.ImageSection:nth-child(3) .ImageSection-hold{
   background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<section class="section ImageSection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ImageSection-hold">
      <div class="ImageSection__desc">
        asd
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section ImageSection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ImageSection-hold">
      <div class="ImageSection__desc">
      zxc
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section ImageSection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ImageSection-hold">
      <div class="ImageSection__desc">
      qwe
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Works perfect @mindmaster thank you for the quick response